# AWS EC2 temporarily failed to connect to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

Last Friday evening I have experienced an issue - ECS task failed to connect to RDS PostgreSQL.

- `The operation has timed out` error on ECS side.
- `Could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer` error on RDS side.

The issue was temporary and went away by itself, but my product was not accessible for ~45minutes during peak time.
I want to understand why that happened and how I can prevent such issues in future.

I have following setup:

- 4 EC2 instances that hosts my ECS tasks (.net core).
- There several types of tasks: 4 Back-end ECS tasks, 1 Admin ECS task, 1 background worker ECS task, etc.
- RDS PostgreSQL DB that has limited access via VPC security groups.
- There's "internal" security group. It references itself to allow all incoming traffic within this security group. EC2 instances and RDS DB are both part of this security group.

During the time of issue, Admin ECS task and Background worker ECS tasks were able to access DB.

Meanwhile all 4 Back-end ECS tasks were getting time out errors.
I believe all 4 Back-end ECS tasks were running on 2 EC2 instances. Therefore I assume those 2 EC2 instances had issues connecting to DB. But I am not entirely sure of it.

Any ideas on why this could have happened?
How can I prevent such issues in future?

Comment: Have you checked your patch maintenance time to see if these coincide? Alternatively if your resources were in AP-Northeast-1 there were some impairments on Friday

Comment: @ChrisWilliams you mean RDS maintenance window? 
RDS instance is maintained on a different day of week and different time.
Our region is eu-west-1

Comment: Hmm ok, anything in the RDS events history? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ListEvents.html

Comment: @ChrisWilliams nothings were, as it holds history for past 24 hours only :(
Is there a way to enforce certain ECS task to be launched on different EC2 servers?